# Xamarin Zebra Sdk - bluetooth printing "read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1"

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.android, zebra-printers

I'm using the latest Xamarin Zebra SDK to print to a ZQ520 Printer. Approximately **70% of the time printing works fine**. The other 30% of the time it fails with the error

> "read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1"

and the printer needs to be switched off/on for printing to work.

The content I'm sending is a signature and label and I'm printing over an insecure Bluetooth Connection.

It's proving difficult to reproduce the error consistently. I'm thinking it might have to do with the initialResponseTimeout and responseCompletionTimeout in my code below. Has anyone any experience with setting these values?

```
        IConnection connection = null;

        try
        {

            connection = new BluetoothConnectionInsecure(address);
            connection.Open();

            using (var printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.GetInstance(
                               PrinterLanguage.Cpcl, connection))
            {

                using (var image = ZebraImageFactory.GetImage(signature))
                {
                   printer.StoreImage(SignatureFilename, image,
                              image.Width, image.Height);
                }

                // pause to ensure image is saved
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                var initialResponseTimeout = 3000;
                var responseCompletionTimeout = 1000;

                // is the timeout too small or large ?
                connection.SendAndWaitForResponse(printLabel,
                initialResponseTimeout, responseCompletionTimeout, null);
            }

        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.Crashes.TrackError(exception);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: any update? i face the same issue

Comment: What is the object passed in "PrintLabel"??

Comment: Any update? I am facing the same issue.  How to achieve printer connection before sending the print command.

I am using ZQ510 Zebra mobile printer. and testing with android 12 devices. Printer is discoverable and able to pair it with the device but unable to connect it.

Answer (score 0):

I had related problems when i was trying to connect direct with my devices.
I suggest you to create an application in your local  computer to communicate with your mobile phone, and your printer. Also try to increase timeout inside your code.

```
 using (var printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.GetInstance(
                           PrinterLanguage.Cpcl, connection))
        {

            using (var image = ZebraImageFactory.GetImage(signature))
            {
               printer.StoreImage(SignatureFilename, image,
                          image.Width, image.Height);
            }

            // pause to ensure image is saved
            //Thread.Sleep(1000); I recommend you to remove this line

            var initialResponseTimeout = 15000;
            var responseCompletionTimeout = 15000;

            // is the timeout too small or large ?
            connection.SendAndWaitForResponse(printLabel,
            initialResponseTimeout, responseCompletionTimeout, null);
        }
```

Comment: Hi Dim, I can't use an app on my computer, it's an Android App. Do you know what timeouts you set?

Comment: Just try to set it 15 seconds.(15000). It works better? Did you get any exception? Check my updated answer. I also recommend to delete thread sleeping, maybe printer is answering very quick sometimes and you dont manage to listen, that all operation was success.